# Dynamically create Lua module from string

Tags: lua

I'm in the following situation (please don't question my motives):

I have a Lua script `foo.lua` that requires some module `bar`, i.e.:

```
-- foo.lua
require 'bar'

-- more code
```

There should however be no `bar.lua` file implementing this module. What I would like to do instead is to execute `foo.lua` from another script `main.lua` which should also *dynamically create the module `bar` from a string* (where the string comes from is not important), i.e.:

```
-- main.lua

-- somehow create module `bar` such that `require bar` in `foo.lua` will succeed

dofile('foo.lua')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This looks like a circular dependency, which is generally not possible. `main.lua` requires `foo.lua` (in the `dofile` call), and `foo.lua` requires `main.lua` (to create `bar`). Maybe you could use `main.lua` to create the `bar.lua` file before calling `dofile`.

Comment: `package.preload.bar = loadstring(bar_str)()`

Comment: Possibly plus/minus a pair of parentheses.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I think that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to use `package.preload` which lets you
assign a module resolver function given a module name:

```lua
local myBar = { message = "Hello from BAR!" }

package.preload['bar'] = function(...)
    return myBar
end
```

You could also just set the module directly in `package.loaded`, this lets
you override already loaded modules for the next time require() is called also:

```lua
local myBar = { message = "Hello from BAR!" }
local myBar2 = { message = "I've changed!" }

-- using `package.loaded` to say we have already loaded it
package.loaded['bar'] = myBar
print(require('bar').message)
package.loaded['bar'] = myBar2
print(require('bar').message)
```

If you need to be more dynamic you could always override the require function:

```lua
local myBar = {
  message = "Hello from BAR!"
}

local oldRequire = require

function require(name)
  if name == "bar" then return myBar end
  return oldRequire(name)
end

local bar = require("bar")

print("Bar says: '"..bar.message.."'")
```

You can check [the module docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.3).  `package.searchers` looks promising for a generic loader, but I don't seem to be able to modify it to include my own.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in a ingame Lua-console to `load()` the functions. The goal is that the required Lua file holds only strings and returning it. Like this one...

```
return {
cmd=[[return function(cm) cm=io.popen(cm, 'r') cm=cm:read('a+') return cm end]]
}
```

Then you can do a...

```
love.code=require('more_functions')
love.cmd=load(love.code.cmd)()
```

In my require there is also an install code that bring it all to the right place. In my case i set up a metatable with the defined functions the whole looks like...

```
-- Name: koys.lua
return {
cat=[[return function(cat) for line in io.lines(cat) do io.write(string.format('%s\n',line)) end end]],
free=[[return function() local a=(collectgarbage('count')*1024) print('Before:',a,'Byte') collectgarbage() print('After:',(collectgarbage('count')*1024),'Byte') a=a-collectgarbage('count')*1024 print('Freed:',a,'Byte') return a end]],
gauss=[[return function(gauss) return ((gauss*gauss+gauss)/2) end]],
shell=[[return function(shell) if (type(shell)=='string') then os.execute(shell) else os.execute('/bin/bash') end end]],
cmd=[[return function(cm) cm=io.popen(cm, 'r') cm=cm:read('a+') return cm end]],
len=[[return function(len) local incr=0 for _ in pairs(len) do incr=incr+1 end return incr end]],
dump=[[return function(dump) for key,value in pairs(dump) do io.write(string.format("%s=%s=%s\n",key,type(value),value)) end end]],
help=[[return function(help) love.dump(getmetatable(help).__index) end]],
printf=[[return function(prf,...) io.write(prf:format(...)) end]],
bl=[[return function(r,g,b,a) love.rrand=function() return r end love.grand=function() return g end love.brand=function() return b end love.arand=function() return a end end]],
install=[[getmetatable(love).__index.cmd=load(package.loaded.koys.cmd)()
getmetatable(love).__index.cat=load(package.loaded.koys.cat)()
getmetatable(love).__index.dump=load(package.loaded.koys.dump)()
getmetatable(love).__index.free=load(package.loaded.koys.free)()
getmetatable(love).__index.len=load(package.loaded.koys.len)()
getmetatable(love).__index.gauss=load(package.loaded.koys.gauss)()
getmetatable(love).__index.shell=load(package.loaded.koys.shell)()
getmetatable(love).__index.printf=load(package.loaded.koys.printf)()
getmetatable(love).__index.help=load(package.loaded.koys.help)()
getmetatable(love).__index.bl=load(package.loaded.koys.bl)()
getmetatable(love).__index.info=debug.getinfo
getmetatable(love).__index.cmd=load(package.loaded.koys.cmd)()
getmetatable(love).__index.concat=table.concat
getmetatable(love).__index.remove=table.remove
getmetatable(love).__index.unpack=table.unpack
getmetatable(love).__index.insert=table.insert
getmetatable(love).__index.sort=table.sort
getmetatable(love).__index.move=table.move
getmetatable(love).__index.pack=table.pack]]
}
```

...and do only..

```
love.code=require('koys') -- This is a table with text elements that holding Lua code
setmetatable(love,{__index={}}) -- ...that will expand love...
load(love.code.install)() -- ...with metamethods.
```

After that the table love will show the content with...

```
love:dump()
```

Or the content of the metatable with...

```
love:help()
```

Screenshot
[image]